# Having A Problem In Importing External Js In App.js React Developmnt

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I Am Trying To Build An Starter App Which Handles SMTP Anonymously In React Development As A Part Of Learning

But Before Getting Into Actual Development , I am Not Looking For Fancy Front-end Here
So I Just Write Basic Showcase Script To verify the code Works Well

Hear My App.js looks Likes
It Is A Simple Script Which Basically Generates Random Keyword Email And Lets You Copy The Mail Address So Every-time i Refresh Page It Gets me A New Mail

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

const characters ='ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';

function generateString(length) 
{
    let result = ' ';
    let addr = "@example.com";
    const charactersLength = characters.length;
    for ( let i = 0; i < length; i++ ) {
        result += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charactersLength));
    }
    result=result+addr;

    return result;
}

var mail=generateString(9)


function CopyIt() {
  
  var copyText = document.getElementById("evar");

  /* Select the text field */
  copyText.select();
  copyText.setSelectionRange(0, 99999);

  /* Copy the text inside the text field */
  document.execCommand("copy");

  /* Alert the copied text */
  alert("Copied the text: " + copyText.value);
}


function App() {
  return (
   <> 
   <pre>
   <h1>This is Temporarily mail site </h1>
   <p>It helps you Access your Anonymous mail without logins Required </p>
   </pre>
   <nav className="navbar navbar-light bg-light">
      <form className="container-fluid">
        <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1">@</span>
        <input type="text" id="evar" class="form-control" value={mail} aria-label="Username" aria-describedby="basic-addon1"></input>
        <button onClick='Copyit()'>Copy text</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </nav>

   </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

But Every-time I Refresh Main App.js I Got Copied Mail of Previously Generated Code
So What I Did Is
Put A New Js File Name logic.js And Put My Both Function genrateStrings And CopyIt
And Imported In App.js

As `import './logic.js'`
In The App.js With Same Src Folder

Now my logic.js Looks like

```
const characters ='ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';

function generateString(length) 
{
    let result = ' ';
    let addr = "@example.com";
    const charactersLength = characters.length;
    for ( let i = 0; i < length; i++ ) {
        result += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charactersLength));
    }
    result=result+addr;

    return result;
}


function CopyIt() {
  
  var copyText = document.getElementById("evar");

  /* Select the text field */
  copyText.select();
  copyText.setSelectionRange(0, 99999);

  /* Copy the text inside the text field */
  document.execCommand("copy");

  /* Alert the copied text */
  alert("Copied the text: " + copyText.value);
}
```

Now When i Try To Run Code I Am Getting Error Like
genrateStrings() And CopyIt() Not Found

I Tried To Update import './logic.js' In public/index.html and src/index.js As well

I Tried Reading This Article On Imporitng Externaljs file [here](https://betterprogramming.pub/4-ways-of-adding-external-js-files-in-reactjs-823f85de3668)

but i couldn't understand cause i am beginer with react

i also tried using this import method

```
const Demo = props => (
  <ScriptTag type="text/javascript" src="logic.js" />
  )
```

but none of them giving me promising result as mentioned

Comment: Hi, please fix your spelling

Comment: @georg I Check It One More Time looks Like The Only The Code Cells Were giving spelling mistakes not the explanation cells

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to export your functions from `logic.js`

```js
export function generateString...

export function CopyIt...
```

And this is how you import them in `App.js`

```js
import { generateString, CopyIt } from './logic.js';
```

Comment: hitting a compilation error in src/logic.js Unexpected token expected "{" before export function CopyIt I doesn't understand why @Luis Sardon

Comment: This Issue Is Still Not Solved

Comment: Can you share how your code looks like now?